# How to run main() Method with Ant Script?

Tags: java, ant

I just want to run the `main()` - Method of a java class by double clicking my
the ant task in eclipse ant - view. My Problem is, I don't know how to write the ant file exactly. My ant file should be `analyzeDatabase.xml`.

I tried something like this, but always fails:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="DBAnalyzer" default="run" basedir=".">
    <target name="run" description="runs dbanalyzer">
        <java classname="DBAnalyzer">
            <arg value="-h"/>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `<java classname="DBAnalyzer">` to fully qualified name.
And don't forget to double-check your classpath.

```
<java classname="com.prostep.openpdm.db.analyzer.DBAnalyzer">
    <arg value="-h"/>
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${your.java.class.path}"/>
    </classpath>
</java>
```

Full description on Ant Java Task is here:
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html